# How can I get this list menu to line up with the content?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have tried setting the margin to 0 to get rid of the indention, changing the text-align to left, as well as played around with the padding for the div and I can't seem to get it to line up with the image, no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<img src="images/gkmlogo.png" alt="God, Kill Me" />
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <right><li><a href=""><img src="images/social_twitter.png" /></a>    </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="images/social_rss.png" /></a></li>         
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="content-comic">
                <div class="comic-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Previous</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Last</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="comic">
            <img src="images/0000.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="comic-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Previous</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Last</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="side"> 
                <h2>Favorite Webcomics</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Webcomic 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Webcomic 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Webcomic 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Webcomic 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Webcomic 5</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
color: #fff;
background-color: #2c2c2c;
}

#container {
background-color: #555555;
width: 1000px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
left:0;
right: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
margin: 5px;
padding: 1px;
text-align: left;
}

#nav {
background-color: #444444;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 1px;
text-align: left;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

.comic-nav {
margin-top: -5px;
padding-left: 0;
}

.comic-nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.comic-nav a, #side ul a {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 10pt;
text-transform: none;
}

#content {
background-color: #444444;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
height: 1125px;
}

#content-comic{
float: left;
background-color: #444444;
width: 70%;
height: 1125px;
overflow: auto;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 12px;
}

#side {
float: right;
background-color: #444444;
width: 25%;
height: 1125px;
overflow: auto;
}

#side ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left:0;
    }
 h2 {
font-size: 16pt;
font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

Thanks so much. I apologize for any extra information, just wanted to be thorough.

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to line up with the image". which image...? there are few images and items in the second picture which is not there in the first picture, which is the desired output. can you make it clear, or provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with proper images..?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. The image is the large black rectangle. If you notice in the first picture, the "First", "Previous", "Next" navigation is lined up vertically on the left hand side with the black image. In the second picture, it is indented. I hope I've cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, it appears the list items are being pushed due to the margin on the UL tag.

Try setting this margin to 0.

```
ul { magin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }

#nav {
padding-left: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried it and it only moved a few pixels but it's still indented. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yeah, a couple of things I can see is that your margin and padding left are differing in these two areas. content div has a total of 15 pixels on left from margin and padding and then content-comic has another 12 px. This totals 27px of space before the ul begins...

Comment: nav div has 6, so this doesnt add up to be equal

Comment: I added this to fiddle, can compare you your css. If you need to adjust the left spacing, remember this is spread across multiple elements in your code, just have to make them add up. http://jsfiddle.net/adamfullen/Pe4Sh/

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have trouble with margins and padding with so many divs. I'll make them equal. Thanks so much.